# Missing permissions when using amplify postConfirmation trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

i used amplifies cli to create a `PostConfirmation` lambda trigger using `amplify update auth` and ran through the setup guide setting `Do you want to enable any of the following capabilities?` to `Add User to Group` which created a template for the specific functionality in `amplify/backend/function//src/add-to-group.js.

I then pushed the function using `amplify push`. Sadly now when a new user gets confirmed it is not added to the wanted group. When checking the logs on that specific lambda i get the following errors:

```
xyzd1aPostConfirmation-dev is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:GetGroup on resource …
xyzd1aPostConfirmation-dev is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:CreateGroup on resource ...
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Shouldn't the created IAM user have the correct permissions for the template file to work? How do i resolve this?

Edit: in the AWS webinterface the lambda has a existing role attached that satisfies the needed permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup",
                "cognito-idp:GetGroup",
                "cognito-idp:CreateGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:xyz:userpool/abc…",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK never mind. The errors somehow only happen when using the lambda test mode in the aws interface.

The Lambda Trigger does NOT trigger when you set up a user in the Cognito User Interface an go from `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` to `CONFIRMED`. It only triggers when you use the actual `signUp` API and go from `UNCONFIRMED` to `CONFIRMED`.

Comment: Thanks for the list of permissions, it helped me to solved another problem. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/7576